# Redis Bit Select All Keys With Offset Value of 1

Tags: redis

If I have a series of keys representing bitmaps in Redis, how can I get a list of all keys whose n bit value is equal to 1. For example, I have the following bitmaps:

```
keyname:20140418:item1: 000111...0010
keyname:20140418:item2: 000101...1010
keyname:20140418:item3: 100011...0010
```

I want to get the list of all items whose first value is 0 which would result in:

```
keyname:20140418:item1
keyname:20140418:item2
```

Answer (score 2):

In Redis, always prepare your data in such a way that retrieval is easy and most of all **scalable**.

When storing the data, accompany the `SET` with a `ZADD zerostartingbitmaps [unixtimestamp] [linkedkey]`

To fix all your data and fill the Sorted Set, use [`SCAN`](http://redis.io/commands/zadd) and [bitwise operations](http://redis.io/commands/getbit).

Hope this helps, TW